# Using 2 image targets to activate 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I don't know much about c# and i just started to vuforia.
I've search for answer on other forums but it seems complicated to me.
need a script that activates image target 1 behaviour if camera sees image target 2 and 3 at the same time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you want to trigger an event if 2 images are visible to the camera? If I get your point correctly... Then this might help you with the issue:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).